# ArcGIS ElevationSync no longer working?

Tags: elevation, arcgis-rest-api

I was using the [ArcGIS REST elevation](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/elevation/api-reference/profilesync.htm) for a year or longer.

However it stopped working, giving http 400 responses. According to documentation nothing changed. Anybody had a same issue or some further information ? Note that this service was slow, but free of charge :

> The Profile task here is functionally equivalent to the one above, with the difference being that there is no charge or licensing restrictions to use it.

A sample which is used to work :

[https://elevation.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tools/ElevationSync/GPServer/Profile/execute?InputLineFeatures={"geometryType":"esriGeometryPolyline","features":[{"geometry":{"paths":[[[13.409970,52.587960],[13.410200,52.587390],[13.407040,52.586420],[13.405330,52.590680],[13.403400,52.590350],[13.401690,52.590030],[13.400480,52.590880],[13.398420,52.592400],[13.396700,52.593640],[13.396150,52.593990],[13.394980,52.594370],[13.388640,52.596300],[13.388640,52.596300],[13.386400,52.596990],[13.384570,52.597760],[13.383130,52.598330],[13.380130,52.599560],[13.379040,52.599980],[13.378910,52.600070],[13.378740,52.600250],[13.378750,52.600430],[13.378730,52.600530],[13.378630,52.600630],[13.379160,52.601190],[13.379940,52.602270],[13.380020,52.602430],[13.380090,52.602650],[13.380110,52.602810],[13.380070,52.602920],[13.380000,52.603020],[13.379900,52.603110],[13.379740,52.603180],[13.377840,52.603880],[13.377770,52.603930],[13.377740,52.604000],[13.375660,52.604710],[13.375770,52.604860],[13.375770,52.604860],[13.375660,52.604710],[13.375460,52.604750],[13.375790,52.605260],[13.376040,52.605810],[13.376180,52.606460],[13.376320,52.606680],[13.376390,52.607310],[13.376480,52.607670],[13.377080,52.608500],[13.377640,52.609380],[13.377630,52.609430],[13.377530,52.609520],[13.378710,52.611240],[13.378730,52.611350],[13.378670,52.611460],[13.375320,52.615880],[13.372050,52.620480],[13.371170,52.621670],[13.370620,52.622270],[13.368950,52.623890],[13.368280,52.624400],[13.368020,52.624560],[13.367850,52.624740],[13.367760,52.624890],[13.367500,52.625520],[13.367400,52.625700],[13.366960,52.625990],[13.366580,52.626330],[13.366200,52.626730],[13.366070,52.626760],[13.360610,52.626690],[13.360260,52.626710],[13.357800,52.627060],[13.356860,52.627200],[13.355730,52.627390],[13.355410,52.627440],[13.355220,52.627460],[13.355040,52.627450],[13.351420,52.626440],[13.351150,52.626370],[13.349800,52.626390],[13.349670,52.626450],[13.348570,52.626510],[13.346980,52.626440],[13.346950,52.627600],[13.346390,52.627600],[13.345280,52.627700],[13.343700,52.627320],[13.343150,52.627290],[13.341000,52.627750],[13.340450,52.627800],[13.340680,52.628450],[13.340350,52.629680],[13.340160,52.630210],[13.340100,52.630320],[13.339370,52.631250],[13.338970,52.631780],[13.335240,52.630930],[13.334000,52.630680],[13.331180,52.630190],[13.327680,52.629950],[13.327210,52.629930],[13.326710,52.629950],[13.325250,52.630080],[13.322500,52.630240],[13.320850,52.630360],[13.320030,52.630510],[13.317850,52.631010],[13.317330,52.631100],[13.317010,52.631150],[13.316660,52.631160],[13.316320,52.631130],[13.314250,52.630660],[13.314100,52.631150],[13.313260,52.630890],[13.313260,52.630890],[13.313160,52.630850],[13.312690,52.630590],[13.312050,52.630560],[13.310360,52.630600],[13.310220,52.631100],[13.310090,52.631060],[13.309200,52.630870],[13.308400,52.630730],[13.307410,52.630620],[13.306870,52.630580],[13.306600,52.630590],[13.306460,52.630600],[13.305870,52.630750],[13.305050,52.631050],[13.304210,52.631250],[13.303590,52.631330],[13.303060,52.631360],[13.300890,52.631390],[13.300450,52.631380],[13.299510,52.631430],[13.298720,52.631510],[13.298130,52.631590],[13.297810,52.631650],[13.296520,52.631940],[13.296190,52.631970],[13.295620,52.631970],[13.294900,52.631880],[13.294620,52.631870],[13.294350,52.631880],[13.294000,52.631950],[13.293570,52.632090],[13.293300,52.632220],[13.292930,52.632500],[13.292540,52.632770],[13.292290,52.632910],[13.291740,52.633190],[13.291630,52.633230],[13.291700,52.633420],[13.291670,52.633670],[13.291590,52.633800],[13.291480,52.633920],[13.291310,52.634040],[13.291100,52.634160],[13.290790,52.634250],[13.290470,52.634280],[13.290230,52.634260],[13.289950,52.634190],[13.289810,52.634120],[13.289770,52.634080],[13.289800,52.634030],[13.290430,52.633500],[13.290320,52.633450],[13.290040,52.633690]]],"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326}}}]}&env:outSR=&env:processSR=&returnZ=true&returnM=false&f=json](https://elevation.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tools/ElevationSync/GPServer/Profile/execute?InputLineFeatures=%7B%22geometryType%22:%22esriGeometryPolyline%22,%22features%22:%5B%7B%22geometry%22:%7B%22paths%22:%5B%5B%5B13.409970,52.587960%5D,%5B13.410200,52.587390%5D,%5B13.407040,52.586420%5D,%5B13.405330,52.590680%5D,%5B13.403400,52.590350%5D,%5B13.401690,52.590030%5D,%5B13.400480,52.590880%5D,%5B13.398420,52.592400%5D,%5B13.396700,52.593640%5D,%5B13.396150,52.593990%5D,%5B13.394980,52.594370%5D,%5B13.388640,52.596300%5D,%5B13.388640,52.596300%5D,%5B13.386400,52.596990%5D,%5B13.384570,52.597760%5D,%5B13.383130,52.598330%5D,%5B13.380130,52.599560%5D,%5B13.379040,52.599980%5D,%5B13.378910,52.600070%5D,%5B13.378740,52.600250%5D,%5B13.378750,52.600430%5D,%5B13.378730,52.600530%5D,%5B13.378630,52.600630%5D,%5B13.379160,52.601190%5D,%5B13.379940,52.602270%5D,%5B13.380020,52.602430%5D,%5B13.380090,52.602650%5D,%5B13.380110,52.602810%5D,%5B13.380070,52.602920%5D,%5B13.380000,52.603020%5D,%5B13.379900,52.603110%5D,%5B13.379740,52.603180%5D,%5B13.377840,52.603880%5D,%5B13.377770,52.603930%5D,%5B13.377740,52.604000%5D,%5B13.375660,52.604710%5D,%5B13.375770,52.604860%5D,%5B13.375770,52.604860%5D,%5B13.375660,52.604710%5D,%5B13.375460,52.604750%5D,%5B13.375790,52.605260%5D,%5B13.376040,52.605810%5D,%5B13.376180,52.606460%5D,%5B13.376320,52.606680%5D,%5B13.376390,52.607310%5D,%5B13.376480,52.607670%5D,%5B13.377080,52.608500%5D,%5B13.377640,52.609380%5D,%5B13.377630,52.609430%5D,%5B13.377530,52.609520%5D,%5B13.378710,52.611240%5D,%5B13.378730,52.611350%5D,%5B13.378670,52.611460%5D,%5B13.375320,52.615880%5D,%5B13.372050,52.620480%5D,%5B13.371170,52.621670%5D,%5B13.370620,52.622270%5D,%5B13.368950,52.623890%5D,%5B13.368280,52.624400%5D,%5B13.368020,52.624560%5D,%5B13.367850,52.624740%5D,%5B13.367760,52.624890%5D,%5B13.367500,52.625520%5D,%5B13.367400,52.625700%5D,%5B13.366960,52.625990%5D,%5B13.366580,52.626330%5D,%5B13.366200,52.626730%5D,%5B13.366070,52.626760%5D,%5B13.360610,52.626690%5D,%5B13.360260,52.626710%5D,%5B13.357800,52.627060%5D,%5B13.356860,52.627200%5D,%5B13.355730,52.627390%5D,%5B13.355410,52.627440%5D,%5B13.355220,52.627460%5D,%5B13.355040,52.627450%5D,%5B13.351420,52.626440%5D,%5B13.351150,52.626370%5D,%5B13.349800,52.626390%5D,%5B13.349670,52.626450%5D,%5B13.348570,52.626510%5D,%5B13.346980,52.626440%5D,%5B13.346950,52.627600%5D,%5B13.346390,52.627600%5D,%5B13.345280,52.627700%5D,%5B13.343700,52.627320%5D,%5B13.343150,52.627290%5D,%5B13.341000,52.627750%5D,%5B13.340450,52.627800%5D,%5B13.340680,52.628450%5D,%5B13.340350,52.629680%5D,%5B13.340160,52.630210%5D,%5B13.340100,52.630320%5D,%5B13.339370,52.631250%5D,%5B13.338970,52.631780%5D,%5B13.335240,52.630930%5D,%5B13.334000,52.630680%5D,%5B13.331180,52.630190%5D,%5B13.327680,52.629950%5D,%5B13.327210,52.629930%5D,%5B13.326710,52.629950%5D,%5B13.325250,52.630080%5D,%5B13.322500,52.630240%5D,%5B13.320850,52.630360%5D,%5B13.320030,52.630510%5D,%5B13.317850,52.631010%5D,%5B13.317330,52.631100%5D,%5B13.317010,52.631150%5D,%5B13.316660,52.631160%5D,%5B13.316320,52.631130%5D,%5B13.314250,52.630660%5D,%5B13.314100,52.631150%5D,%5B13.313260,52.630890%5D,%5B13.313260,52.630890%5D,%5B13.313160,52.630850%5D,%5B13.312690,52.630590%5D,%5B13.312050,52.630560%5D,%5B13.310360,52.630600%5D,%5B13.310220,52.631100%5D,%5B13.310090,52.631060%5D,%5B13.309200,52.630870%5D,%5B13.308400,52.630730%5D,%5B13.307410,52.630620%5D,%5B13.306870,52.630580%5D,%5B13.306600,52.630590%5D,%5B13.306460,52.630600%5D,%5B13.305870,52.630750%5D,%5B13.305050,52.631050%5D,%5B13.304210,52.631250%5D,%5B13.303590,52.631330%5D,%5B13.303060,52.631360%5D,%5B13.300890,52.631390%5D,%5B13.300450,52.631380%5D,%5B13.299510,52.631430%5D,%5B13.298720,52.631510%5D,%5B13.298130,52.631590%5D,%5B13.297810,52.631650%5D,%5B13.296520,52.631940%5D,%5B13.296190,52.631970%5D,%5B13.295620,52.631970%5D,%5B13.294900,52.631880%5D,%5B13.294620,52.631870%5D,%5B13.294350,52.631880%5D,%5B13.294000,52.631950%5D,%5B13.293570,52.632090%5D,%5B13.293300,52.632220%5D,%5B13.292930,52.632500%5D,%5B13.292540,52.632770%5D,%5B13.292290,52.632910%5D,%5B13.291740,52.633190%5D,%5B13.291630,52.633230%5D,%5B13.291700,52.633420%5D,%5B13.291670,52.633670%5D,%5B13.291590,52.633800%5D,%5B13.291480,52.633920%5D,%5B13.291310,52.634040%5D,%5B13.291100,52.634160%5D,%5B13.290790,52.634250%5D,%5B13.290470,52.634280%5D,%5B13.290230,52.634260%5D,%5B13.289950,52.634190%5D,%5B13.289810,52.634120%5D,%5B13.289770,52.634080%5D,%5B13.289800,52.634030%5D,%5B13.290430,52.633500%5D,%5B13.290320,52.633450%5D,%5B13.290040,52.633690%5D%5D%5D,%22spatialReference%22:%7B%22wkid%22:4326%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D&env:outSR=&env:processSR=&returnZ=true&returnM=false&f=json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like server behaviour changed expecting c certain encoding. Having the URL correctly encoded, the endpoint is working.